# Removing _id element from Pymongo results

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm attempting to create a web service using MongoDB and Flask (using the pymongo driver).  A query to the database returns documents with the "_id" field included, of course.  I don't want to send this to the client, so how do I remove it?

Here's a Flask route:

```
@app.route('/theobjects')
def index():
    objects = db.collection.find()
    return str(json.dumps({'results': list(objects)}, 
        default = json_util.default,
        indent = 4))
```

This returns:

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "whatever": {
            "field1": "value", 
            "field2": "value", 
        }, 
        "whatever2": {
            "field3": "value"
        },
        ...
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "..."
        }, 

    ...
    }
]}
```

I thought it was a dictionary and I could just delete the element before returning it:

```
del objects['_id']
```

But that returns a TypeError:

```
TypeError: 'Cursor' object does not support item deletion
```

So it isn't a dictionary, but something I have to iterate over with each result as a dictionary.  So I try to do that with this code:

```
for object in objects:
    del object['_id']
```

Each object dictionary looks the way I'd like it to now, but the objects cursor is empty.  So I try to create a new dictionary and after deleting _id from each, add to a new dictionary that Flask will return:

```
new_object = {}
for object in objects:
    for key, item in objects.items():
        if key == '_id':
            del object['_id']
            new_object.update(object)
```

This just returns a dictionary with the first-level keys and nothing else.

So this is sort of a standard nested dictionaries problem, but I'm also shocked that MongoDB doesn't have a way to easily deal with this.

The [MongoDB documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields) explains that you can exclude _id with

```
{ _id : 0 }
```

But that does nothing with pymongo.  The [Pymongo documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) explains that you can list the fields you want returned, but "(“_id” will always be included)".  Seriously?  Is there no way around this?  Is there something simple and stupid that I'm overlooking here?

Comment: What is your actual claim here? Your code for creating a new dict is weird and not necessary. What is your real problem?

Comment: My problem was that .find({}, {'_id': False}) wasn't excluding _id. However it was a problem with my code and it's now working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: “but the objects cursor is empty”: that’s because you can iterate only  once, so you’d need to iterate, get next dict, remove '_id', put dict into a list, and at the end return that list, not objects.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

To exclude the `_id` field in a find query in pymongo, you can use:

```
db.collection.find({}, {'_id': False})
```

The documentation is somewhat missleading on this as it says the `_id` field is always included. But you can exclude it like shown above.

Comment: Thanks, this is correct.  I had tried this before posting but I guess there was a problem with the string I was passing in the first parameter.  I fixed that and now all is good.

Answer (score 2):

Above answer fails if we want specific fields and still ignore _id. Use the following in such cases:

```
db.collection.find({'required_column_A':1,'required_col_B':1, '_id': False})
```

Comment: The `'_id': False` should be in the second set of curly brackets, not the first (like Thomas' answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
del objects['_id']
```

on the cursor object!

The cursor object is obviously an iterable over the result set and not single
document that you can manipulate.

```
for obj in objects:
     del obj['_id']
```

is likely what you want.

So your claim is completely wrong as the following code shows:

```
import pymongo

c = pymongo.Connection()
db = c['mydb']
db.foo.remove({})
db.foo.save({'foo' : 42})

for row in db.foo.find():
    del row['_id']
    print row



$ bin/python foo.py 

> {u'foo': 42}
```

Comment: Yep, I tried your code too before originally posting.  But how would I then combine these nested dictionaries into one dictionary that can be passed to the client?  

Also, I realized that I was trying to del on a cursor object, that's why I said "So it isn't a dictionary, but something I have to iterate over with each result as a dictionary."  Maybe I should have left out my discovery process but I thought the more info the better.